# Flying Text in 3D (Silverlight) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, animation

I am trying to understand a code that I found online to fly the text in 3d using silverlight. The algorithm is not easy to understand for me as I am not familiar with these types of algos. Does somebody know a good book/resource that talks about these algos?

Comment: Have a link to the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Silverlight-specific, but [WPF Unleashed](http://adamnathan.net/wpf/) is a great reference text that includes chapters on 3d and animation. [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) is (for the most part) a superset of Silverlight's UI system, but most of the same principles apply.